# Issue with previewing data in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008

I have been having some issues previewing data in SSRS lately. I confirm that the datasources connections and datasets are fully correct. In my first example, when I preview the report, I cannot see the row containing the Total for each school. It does not display the label neither in the preview mode.

[image]

However, for the same report, when I preview it and try to export to Excel, bingo! the label and the total appears.
I thought it was maybe a bug on SSRS (within Visual Studio), so I downloaded Report Builder instead which was working fine till this morning.

Again, when I tried to preview the report, it is now returning me blank rows (although if I export to Excel, all the data is here). The same thing is happening in Report Builder, and I am stuck.

[image]

I wonder if anyone else has encountered similar issues, and if so, please let me know any workaround.

I am running Windows 10 Home Edition, and Visual Studio 2019, with the latest version of SSRS and Report Builder.

Comment: Perhaps the cabced data is wrong. I would suggest refreshing it, or deleted the cached data file for the report in your VS Project for that report.

Comment: Tried that by following the link below to delete cache, but data still not showing in Preview:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40149.ssrs-how-to-remove-cached-report-data-in-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: I have come across a temporary workaround in a different post. Apparently, if you change the font size to a different font size (e.g. Arial, 10) from the default font size (e.g Segoe UI, 10), then it works! See post -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359194/ssrs-report-not-displaying-data?rq=1

Comment: You can also change the height besides changing font or font size